# c# what is the efficent way to do this code - style php "eval"

Tags: c#, variable-assignment, label

i  have a windows application in c# , in the form i have 12 labels with the names

```
label1, label2 , ...............
```

i have array of 12 numbers (after some  calculate)

like :

```
int[] nums = new int[12] {1, 0, 4, 6,.............};
```

i want to assign in loop to every label item a value from the array Respectively

something like

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
     label+i.Text = nums[i-1].ToString();
   }
```

what is the efficient  way to do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a corresponding array of labels:

```
Label[] labels = new Label[12] { label1, label2, ... };

for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    labels[i].Text = nums[i].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If all of the labels belong to the same control (a Panel for instance), you can use the find control to perform this assignment:

```
for(int i = 0;i < 12; i++)
{
    Label lbl = myPanel.FindControl("Label" + i.ToString());
    lbl.Text = nums[i].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Bryan's solution is more efficient.

Comment: @yodaj007 - Efficient for cycles but not for storage space. In either case, we're talking about trivial resource difference so it becomes more a matter of code style. Both achieve the same result ultimately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FindControl` method to locate a control based on the name:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++) {
  (Form.FindControl("label" + i.ToString()) as Label).Text = nums[i].ToString();
}
```